# How to set a variable value in a widget and in another widget?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, setstate

I'm trying to set a variable value (number, in the code below) that exists in FirstWidget, from SecondWidget. And notify both widgets so the number will be updated in the two widgets.

```
class FirstWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FirstWidgetState createState() => _FirstWidgetState();
}

class _FirstWidgetState extends State<FirstWidget> {
  int number = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Text(
          '$number',
        ),
        SecondWidget(),
        Text(
          '$number',
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}

class SecondWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SecondWidgetState createState() => _SecondWidgetState();
}

class _SecondWidgetState extends State<SecondWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextButton(
      child: Text('The number is $number. Press to increase the number'),
      onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
          number++;
        });
      },
    );
  }
}
```

(I know that that code gives an error, but the main idea was to give you the problem I want to solve).

The output I want it to be shown:

before pressing the button -

```
0
The number is 0. Press to increase the number
0
```

after pressing the button -

```
1
The number is 1. Press to increase the number
1
```

So I would be happy if you can help solving this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are many approaches to get the result you are looking for, this one is using **ValueNotifier** in order to change the value of **number**

Here is an example based on your code:

https://dartpad.dev/b6409e10de32b280b8938aa75364fa7b

We can use another State Management like Provider or Cubit, and we will get the same result.

Another way is to pass a function as a param in the second widget and execute that function when button is pressed